# How to use theme colors in ngx-admin theme

Tags: angular, sass

I am new to Angular and I am trying to learn it by using [ngx-admin](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin) theme. It uses Sass for styling and in one of my components I want to set background color of div. However I want to use one of the colors provided by the theme so that if user toggles the theme the color can change. I cannot figure out how to use global colors of the theme in my component's scss file.

This is what I want

```
.product-container{
    background:#3d3780; // Instead of using a hard coded color, I want to use theme color here
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I was able to find out how to use theme global colors.

Firs you need to import global theme styles by importing

```
@import '~@nebular/theme/styles/theming';
@import '~@nebular/theme/styles/themes';
```

Then I can set color like this

```
@include nb-install-component() {
    .product-container{
        background:nb-theme(color-bg);
    }
  }
```

We need to wrap our styles inside the @include nb-install-component() call so that styles are refreshed when user changes theme.

For anyone interested in further reading, [here](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/3.6.2/docs/guides/enable-theme-system#enable-theme-system) is the official documentation of the theme.